# Dividing a list into sub elements by referencing to date

Tags: r, list

I have a data like below. It is just sample of my data. Real data much larger.

```
data<-structure(list(date = structure(c(1420443000, 1420443060, 1420443120, 
                                  1420443180, 1420443240, 1420443300, 1420529400, 1420529460, 1420529520, 
                                  1420529580, 1420529640, 1420529700, 1420615800, 1420615860, 1420615920, 
                                  1420615980, 1420616040, 1420616100), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                                  ), tzone = ""), x = c(308.3211, 307.711, 306.2907, 305.9507, 
                                                        306.7108, 306.2307, 301.71, 301.0799, 301.2999, 302.05, 302.5301, 
                                                        302.5201, 297.5993, 297.0392, 296.2791, 295.999, 296.3491, 296.1591
                                  )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

I want to create a list which have i elements. Each i'th element will consist a xts element for one day.

For example for the below data(let say "ldata" is the list name:

ldata[[1]] will be as below:

```
date                 x
2015-01-05 09:30:00 308.3211
2015-01-05 09:31:00 307.7110
2015-01-05 09:32:00 306.2907
2015-01-05 09:33:00 305.9507
2015-01-05 09:34:00 306.7108
2015-01-05 09:35:00 306.2307
```

ldata[[2]] will be as below:

```
date                 x
2015-01-06 09:30:00 301.7100
2015-01-06 09:31:00 301.0799
2015-01-06 09:32:00 301.2999
2015-01-06 09:33:00 302.0500
2015-01-06 09:34:00 302.5301
2015-01-06 09:35:00 302.5201
```

ldata[[3]] will be as below:

```
date                 x
2015-01-07 09:30:00 297.5993
2015-01-07 09:31:00 297.0392
2015-01-07 09:32:00 296.2791
2015-01-07 09:33:00 295.9990
2015-01-07 09:34:00 296.3491
2015-01-07 09:35:00 296.1591
```

How can i do this at R?

I will be very glad for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split` on the `Date` converted 'date' column

```
ldata <- split(data, as.Date(data$date))
ldata[[1]]
#                 date        x
#1 2015-01-05 02:30:00 308.3211
#2 2015-01-05 02:31:00 307.7110
#3 2015-01-05 02:32:00 306.2907
#4 2015-01-05 02:33:00 305.9507
#5 2015-01-05 02:34:00 306.7108
#6 2015-01-05 02:35:00 306.2307
ldata[[2]]
#                  date        x
#7  2015-01-06 02:30:00 301.7100
#8  2015-01-06 02:31:00 301.0799
#9  2015-01-06 02:32:00 301.2999
#10 2015-01-06 02:33:00 302.0500
#11 2015-01-06 02:34:00 302.5301
#12 2015-01-06 02:35:00 302.5201
ldata[[3]]
#                  date        x
#13 2015-01-07 02:30:00 297.5993
#14 2015-01-07 02:31:00 297.0392
#15 2015-01-07 02:32:00 296.2791
#16 2015-01-07 02:33:00 295.9990
#17 2015-01-07 02:34:00 296.3491
#18 2015-01-07 02:35:00 296.1591
```